$N( (p) \mathcal{O}_F) = p^n$, where $n:=[ F : \mathbb{Q}]$, $F$ is a number field ( Norm of ideal )?
I want to solve next problem ( Richard A. Mollin, Algebraic number theory, p.151, # 3.43 )

Let $F$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{P}$ be a nonzero prime $\mathcal{O}_F$-ideal. Prove that $N(\mathfrak{P})=p^m$, where $\mathfrak{P} \cap \mathbb{Z} = (p)$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $m \le [F : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Since $\mathcal{O}_F$ is dedekind domain, $(p) \mathcal{O}_F$ decomposes in a unique way into a product of prime ideals so that $(p)\mathcal{O}_F = \mathfrak{P} I$ for some ideal $I$ in $\mathcal{O}_F$. ( $\because$ The prime ideals occuring in the decomposition are precisely those prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_F$ which lie over $(p)$ ). Since the norm of ideal is multiplicative, we get $N(\mathfrak{P}) | N( (p) \mathcal{O}_F)$. If $N( (p) \mathcal{O}_F) = p^n$, $n:=[ F : \mathbb{Q}]$, then the possible values of $N(\mathfrak{P})$ are $p, p^2 , \dots ,p^n$ and we are done. But $N( (p) \mathcal{O}_F) = p^n$ is really true? If so, why? Perhaps, we may use that for a principal ideal $(\alpha)$ of $\mathcal{O}_F$, we have the identity $N( ( \alpha)) = | N_{F|\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|$ ( the norm of element : C.f. Neukrich, Algebraic number theory p.8, (2.5) definition ). Or is there any other route to show the problem?..

You can apply the result you cited ($N((\alpha)) = |N(\alpha)|$) immediately to finish the proof, since $N((p)\mathcal{O}_F) = N(p) = p^{[F : \mathbb{Q}]}$. Alternatively, you can use the fundamental result that $\sum e_i f_i = [F : \mathbb{Q}]$, where the $e_i$ and $f_i$ are the ramification and inertia degrees for the primes above a fixed rational prime $p$. Then you see (by multiplicativity, as you mentioned) that $N((p)\mathcal{O}_F) = N(\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_n^{e_n}) = \sum e_i N(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \sum e_i f_i = [F : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Thank you : ) Why $N(p) = p^{[F:\mathbb{Q}]}$ ( Key point ) ? Can you explain this calculation more in detail? And for the second attempt, it seems somewhat weired. We want to show $N((p)\mathcal{O}_F)= p^{[F:\mathbb{Q}]}$, not $N((p)\mathcal{O}_F)=[F:\mathbb{Q}]$.

O.K. In the Mollin's book, the norm is defined as follows : Let $F$ be an algebraic number field of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\theta_j$ for $j=1,2, \dots ,d $ be the embeddings of $F$ in $\mathbb{C}$. For each element $\alpha \in F$, set $$  N_F(\alpha)= \prod_{j=1}^{d} \theta_j(\alpha),$$ called the norm of $\alpha$ from $F$. If $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a rational prime,  then since $\theta_j$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ ( True? ) , $N_F(p) = p^d$. Correct?  Thank you.

Yes, this is exactly right! The norm of a rational number is that number raised to the degree of the extension, and the trace is that number times the degree of the extension.

O.K. Thank you ~
